# Date difference comparison syntax

Tags: sql, openedge, progress-db

I need the correct syntax that will get me the difference between two date fields in days when greater than `30`. So in SQL it would be:

```
DATEDIFF(days,field1, field2) > 30
```

What would be the equivalent in Progress?

Comment: And if the difference is <= 30, what result do you want?

Comment: I have never used Progress, but a quick search showed that it seems you can use `INTERVAL (field1, field2, 'days')`.

Answer (score 2):

If the fields are of type DATE then you just subtract them:

```
define variable d1 as date no-undo.
define variable d2 as date no-undo.

d1 = 1/1/1970.
d2 = today.

display d2 - d1.
```

or:

```
display interval(  d2, d1, "days" ).
```

The INCREMENT() function works with fields that are of type DATE, DATETIME or DATETIME-TZ.

Comment: up vote
0
down vote
Could always use following if you wanted to use interval but the variables were dates: 
display interval( datetime(d2), datetime(d1), "days" ).

Comment: No need to convert to DATETIME, interval() works with DATE or DATETIME

Comment: Yeah, I should of checked that. Took your original comment as gospel. My bad!